# Spring-boot-starter-data-rest OneToMany and ManyToOne and collections null pointer execption during POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hateoas

I having this interesting issues trying to POST a JSON string to an HATEOAS REST service I am working on.

When I POST this

```
{
    "type" : "Ladies",
    "name" : "Pants",
    "description" : "This is a test category
}
```

without a Product Collection, I get the required response 201, Created.

But when I attempt to post this

```
{
    "type" : "Ladies",
    "name" : "Pants",
    "description" : "This is a test category",
    "products" : [
        {
            "type" : "some type",
            "name" : "Super shoes"
        },

        {
            "type" : "some type 2",
            "name" : "Super shoes 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[qtp655641627-165] ERROR org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController - Could not read JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: test.Category["products"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: test.Category["products"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: test.Category["products"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: test.Category["products"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1666)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: test.Category["products"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3023)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:359)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:227)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:204)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
    ... 57 more
[qtp655641627-165] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ExceptionMessage> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.handleNotReadable(org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:340)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1666)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:257)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1636)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here are my ORM models:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Data
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "sorElements")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8969734693918596364L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Category category;
}


package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Data
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "sorElements")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1131387462609255626L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

}


package test;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "cats", path = "cats")
public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Category, BigInteger>{

}
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something here, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ensure that you are running the same spring version everywhere? This can cause weird errors... In eclipse you can see that when you open the pom.xml file and click in Dependency-hierarchy then type spring in a search field the upper right corner.

Comment: I am actually using spring-boot-starter pom so I am pretty sure that is what I am doing except something is wrong with this version   @Zarathustra

Comment: _**`<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>`**_

Comment: Can you post your Category model? try initializing the products collection (where it is declared) in the Category object if it isn't already set.

Comment: just guessing, can an array be marshaled into a set?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the stack trace, you get a hint that Spring is expecting a URI, instead of a collection of products. Which means you should post your products first, and then include a list of the URIs to these products instead of the actual content of them.

It used to possible choose whether to post nested/embedded entity representations or to post links to already exisiting resources, but somewhere along the road this (unintentionally I hope) stopped working.

You could try to override the spring-data-rest-webmvc version and downgrade to 2.1.0.RELEASE, in order to verify. I also think this is closely related to a (yet unresolved) bug in Spring Data REST: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-377.